# Reading xml and lookup in controller?

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-3, xmlnode, xml-attribute

I have a sample xml

```
<Lookup> 
    <Controller Name="Activity1" >
       <action Name="Editactivity1" appgroup="Something" productcode="SomethingElse"/>    
    </Controller> 
    <Controller Name="Activity2">    
       <action Name="Editactivity2" appgroup="Something1" productcode="SomethingElse2"/>  
    </Controller>
</Lookup>
```

I have the controller name and action name stored in variables.

```
var cntName;
var actName;
```

Based on these values I have to look up this Xml and fetch the corresponding `appgroup` and `productcode` values.

Note: example values for `cntName` would be `Activity1` or `Activity2` or `ActivityN`.
Example values for `actName` would be `EditActivity1` or `EditActivity2` or `EditActivityN`.

So based on these values i have to look up the xml, Hope I am clear with my problem statement.

I am reading my xml using traditional xmldatadocument, how do i change it to LINQ? Sample below.

```
XmlDocument xmlDocAppMod = new XmlDocument();
strFileName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppModOptListPath"].ToString();
strFileLocation = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + strFileName);

xmlDocAppMod.Load(strFileLocation);
```

Thanks,
Adarsh

Comment: Is it right, that `actName` is the value of `Name` attribute? What is then the `cntName`?

Comment: Hmmm there are two different name attributes , one for controller which is in the outer level and one more for action which is inside controller node, Let me know if it is wrong and it has to be given a different name

Comment: Oh, ok! Didn't see the `Lookup` tag first? Does "mvc" tag means ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you have several options:

1. Load the document from disk and create an xPath expression to evaluate it:

   ```
   var doc = new XmlDocument();
   doc.Load(fileName);
   var node = doc.SelectSingleNode(
       string.Format("/Lookup/Controller[@Name='{0}']/action[@Name='{1}']", cntName, actName));

   if (node != null)
   {

           var appGroup = node.Attributes["appgroup"].Value;
           var productcode = node.Attributes["productcode"].Value;
   }
   ```
2. Another option could be to use XDocument:

   ```
       var doc = XDocument.Load("");
       var action = doc.Descendants("Controller")
           .Where(c =>
                      {
                          var controllerName = c.Attribute("Name");
                          return controllerName != null && controllerName.Value.Equals(cntName);
                      })
           .FirstOrDefault()
           .Elements("action")
           .Where(a =>
                      {
                          var controllerName = a.Attribute("Name");
                          return controllerName != null && controllerName.Value.Equals(actName);
                      })
           .FirstOrDefault();
       var appGroup = action.Attribute("appgroup").Value;
       var productCode = action.Attribute("productcode").Value;
   ```

**UPDATE:**

Of course, you could use xPath with Linq-to-XML as well:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("");
var action = (XElement) doc.XPathEvaluate(string.Format("/Lookup/Controller[@Name='{0}']/action[@Name='{1}']", cntName, actName));
var appGroup = action.Attribute("appgroup").Value;
var productCode = action.Attribute("productcode").Value;
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you elaborate //Read other values from here ?